# android runtime error?

Tags: android, android-activity

The programme below is trying to take a single text from the first edit box and match the word vysh and produce the output in the second editbox .The second edit box has dots initially and if each word matches the word VYSH then it replaces the dots .

I get an error while running the programme and the error is the following:

```
09-14 19:47:25.593: D/AndroidRuntime(469): Shutting down VM
09-14 19:47:25.593: W/dalvikvm(469): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:505)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.example.testinput.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
09-14 19:47:25.593: E/AndroidRuntime(469):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 19:47:30.175: I/Process(469): Sending signal. PID: 469 SIG: 9
```

The program is shown below:

```
package com.example.testinput;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String rword="vysh";
private StringBuffer gword=new StringBuffer();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final EditText output=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  //input dots in edittext
    char positions[] = new char[rword.length()];
    for (int i=0; i<rword.length(); i++) {
        positions[i] = '.';

}
    String dots=new String(positions);
    output.setText(dots);
    //end of input dots

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                            String str="";

            str=text.getText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(str))
            {           
            //String t=new String(gword);
            char a=str.charAt(0);
            //replace dots with text 
            for (int i=0; i<rword.length(); i++)
            {
                if((rword.charAt(i))==a)
                {
                    gword.setCharAt( i, a);
                }

            }
            //print the output
            output.setText(gword);
            }end of iftextutils         
        }
    }); 
     }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;}
```

}

Tried initializing stringbuffer and edited the program based on below solutioons but the program  doesn't work...I get the following error:09-17 10:48:11.169: 09-17 11:36:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(926): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 length=0
09-17 11:36:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.indexAndLength(AbstractStringBuilder.java:214)
09-17 11:36:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.setCharAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:544)
09-17 11:36:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at java.lang.StringBuffer.setCharAt(StringBuffer.java:698)
09-17 11:36:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.example.testinput.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:60)
09-17 11:36:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)

It shows there is an error at String.charat function ..Basically i want to replace the dots in the editbox to characters in the first box if it matches the word vysh.

Comment: the word is outputed after the button is clicked.....

Comment: Learn to read stack trace. It clearly says "(MainActivity.java:46)" look for NPE there

Comment: tried your solution but it doestn work.Please check above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `String t=new String(gword);`, the variable `gword` is null, which causes the Exception. As far as I can see, you're not using `t` anyways, so ... remove the line, or create `t` with a simple `new String()`.

Comment: well this is a different error now. gword is empty so you cannot set a character at say position 3. This results in an IndexOutOfBounds Exception. The simplest solution for you would be to initialize gword with a number of spaces. Add this line directly after positions[i] = '.'; : `gword.append(" ");`. This gives you a gword with all spaces so setCharAt() should not fail anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because your `gword` in declared but NOT initialized.
So, initialize it and it will work fine. Do something like:

`private StringBuffer gword = new StringBuffer();`

Comment: Tried the following it doesn't work...I get the following error:

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String str="";
str=text.getText().toString();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)){
        //String t=new String(gword);
        char a=str.charAt(0);
        //replace dots with text 
        for (int i=0; i<rword.length(); i++)
        {
            if((rword.charAt(i))==a)
            {
                gword.setCharAt( i, a);
            }

        }
        //print the output
        output.setText(gword);

}
```

Comment: hey,tried that now...it still does'nt work.posted the errors above.

Answer (score 0):

the correct code is :
   package com.example.testinput;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
String rword="vysh";
private StringBuffer gword=new StringBuffer();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final EditText output=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  //input dots in edittext
    char positions[] = new char[rword.length()];
    for (int i=0; i<rword.length(); i++) {
        positions[i] = '.';gword.append(" ");

}
    String dots=new String(positions);
    output.setText(dots);
    //end of input dots

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // to get input edibox
            EditText text=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String str="";
            str=text.getText().toString();


            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(str))
            {
            //String t=new String(gword);


            char a=str.charAt(0);
            //replace dots with text 
            for (int i=0; i<rword.length(); i++)
            {
                if((rword.charAt(i))==a)
                {
                    gword.setCharAt( i, a);


                }

            }
            //print the output
            output.setText(gword);
            }   //end of if textuitls       
        }
    }); 
     }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}